# find a missing number using limited memory

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem is, given an input file with four billion **unique** integers, provide an algorithm to generate an integer which is not contained in the file, assume only have 10 MB of memory.

Searched for some solutions and posted code below, one of which is to store integers into bit-vector blocks (each block representing a specific range of integers among 4 billion range, each bit in the block represent for an integer), and using another counter for each block, to count the number of integers in each block. So that if number of integers is less than the block capacity for integers, scan the bit-vector of the block to find which are missing integers.

My question for this solution is, **why "the nearer to the middle that we pick, the less memory will be used at any given time"**, here are more context,

The array in the first pass can fit in 10 megabytes, or roughly 2^23 bytes, of memory. Since each element in the array is an int, and an int is 4 bytes, we can hold an array of at most about 2^21 elements. So, we can deduce the following:

[image]

Therefore, we can conclude the following:
2^10< rangeSize <2^26, and these conditions give us a good amount of "wiggle room," but the nearer to the middle that we pick, the less memory will be used at any given time.

```
public class QuestionB {
    public static int bitsize = 1048576; // 2^20 bits (2^17 bytes)
    public static int blockNum = 4096; // 2^12
    public static byte[] bitfield = new byte[bitsize/8];
    public static int[] blocks = new int[blockNum];

    public static void findOpenNumber() throws FileNotFoundException {
        int starting = -1;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (new FileReader ("Chapter 10/Question10_3/input_file_q10_3.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            blocks[n / (bitfield.length * 8)]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            if (blocks[i] < bitfield.length * 8){
                /* if value < 2^20, then at least 1 number is missing in
                 * that section. */
                starting = i * bitfield.length * 8;
                break;
            }
        }

        in = new Scanner(new FileReader("Chapter 10/Question10_3/input_file_q10_3.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            /* If the number is inside the block that’s missing 
             * numbers, we record it */
            if (n >= starting && n < starting + bitfield.length * 8) {
                bitfield [(n-starting) / 8] |= 1 << ((n - starting) % 8);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < bitfield.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                /* Retrieves the individual bits of each byte. When 0 bit 
                 * is found, finds the corresponding value. */
                if ((bitfield[i] & (1 << j)) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i * 8 + j + starting);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        findOpenNumber();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your question why the middle between 2¹⁰ and 2²⁶ takes less memory?

Comment: Does the file have four billion _unique_ integers?  Or, are duplicates a possibility?

Comment: You forgot to clearly state your question. After reading your post, I can only think "thats interesting, but what are you asking?"

Comment: Are numbers unique? And are they consecutive, except for the one missing?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, good question, yes, they are unique.

Comment: @Durandal, sorry for any confusion and if you have any unclear parts, let me know and I am happy to edit to improve. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, good question, they are unique numbers.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes, any insights are appreciated. :)

Comment: Since int range is from around -2b to +2b, and you say the set is distinct, negative numbers must exist right? So this causes negative array index eval in first while loop.

Comment: @hsnkhrmn, good catch. Another thing I found in the code which could improve is, I think we can safely change bitfield.length*8 to bitsize, correct?

Comment: Ok, now it's clear to me that the numbers are unique, but, do they also form a *sequence* (except for the missing number)? For example, if instead of 4 billion numbers there were only 5 numbers in the range `1..6`, such as in `1 5 6 4 3` (with missing number being `2`).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, for "form a sequence", you mean ordered?

Comment: @LinMa Not necessarily. I mean that, when you order them, they do form a secuence, except for the missing number.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, thanks for clarify, but I think ordering them is less efficiency than the method I post above?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, looking forward to. :)

Comment: @LinMa Do you know the range of the numbers?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I do not know, and I only know it is non-negative integers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you form M blocks each of size 2^32/M, the total memory required is M+2^27/M words (32 bits). This function reaches a minimum when M=√2^27, which is halfway between 1 and 2^27 blocks. The minimum is 2^14.5 words, about 92 KBytes.

This is very clear on a bilogarithmic plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yves, how do you get `M+2^27/M` words (32 bits)?

Comment: @LinMa: One 32 bits counter per group and 2^32/M bits.

Comment: Thanks Yves, and what do you mean word? Do you mean 32-bit integer?

Comment: @LinMa: yes, I wrote it.

Comment: Thanks Yves, and then, how do you get minimum when M=√2^27?

Comment: Hi Yves, calculate minimal by calculating derivative?

Comment: @LinMa: for instance.

Comment: Thanks Yves, another thing I found in the code which could improve is, I think we can safely change bitfield.length*8 to bitsize, correct?

Comment: @LinMa: sorry, I am no more spending time on this.

Comment: Thanks Yves, appreciate if you could share experience if not using derivative, how to find the minimal value? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Yves, mark your reply as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like this question. I'll give it additional thought but I think if disk space and time is not an issue, you can break the numbers into 100k blocks, and sort them in each file. Any block that doesn't have 100k entries will have a gap. It's not elegant at all but it gets the ball rolling.

Comment: Thanks ajacian81, your insights about memory utilization is also appreciated. :))